# Excel VBA - Ignore column in between non-contiguous user selection

Tags: excel, vba

To get the selected range made by a user, I was doing the following:

```
Dim userSelection As Range
Set userSelection = Selection
```

But I noticed when I use CTRL and only select columns A and C, userSelection is set to be 3 columns wide, it is including the one in between. So if I were to do `userSelection.Columns(2).Cells` It would retrieve me the B column, when I have only selected columns A and C.

It would be easy enough if I were strictly trying to get 2 separate selection areas, just get the first and last columns in the range, but say I also wanted to select column N, in addition to A and C, the first and last column idea would exclude column C.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 3 |
| 2 |  | 2 |
| 3 |  | 1 |

[image: 1]

I'm not sure if Excel sees this type of selection any different from if I were to simply select the entire thing (A9:C18). The unselected columns won't necessarily be blank so only picking columns with values won't solve the problem.

Ultimately, I would like the selection to appear as being 2 columns, or even 2 separate lists.

Comment: `userSelection.Columns(2).Cells` is one column to the right of the first area of the selection which is why you get column B. It could have be outside the selected areas eg `userSelection.Columns(10).Cells` would be column J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `If` statement is unnecessary to get the same result. `selectedArea` is part of the user's selection, and does not include the range between selections (column B in this case).

```
Dim userSelection As Range

Range("A:A,C:C").Select
Set userSelection = Selection

For Each selectedArea In userSelection.Areas
    For Each selectedColumn In selectedArea.Columns
'        If Intersect(selectedColumn, userSelection) Is Nothing Then
'            MsgBox ("Skipped column")
'        Else
            MsgBox selectedColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value
'        End If
    Next selectedColumn
Next selectedArea
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that, considering it doesn't even fire.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching I figured out that what I was looking for was `Range.Areas`. Here's my code, probably not the most optimized, so I'd be happy to accept other solutions:

```
Dim userSelection As Range
Set userSelection = Selection

For Each selectedArea In userSelection.Areas
    For Each selectedColumn In selectedArea.Columns
        MsgBox selectedColumn.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Next selectedColumn
Next selectedArea
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Understanding areas is useful but they serve no purpose here. Each column (or area) is intersecting with `userSelection` so the first message box will never show. You can simply use `For Each selectedColumn In userSelection.Columns: MsgBox CStr(selectedColumn.Cells(1).Value): Next selectedColumn`.